# CPU consumption on a JSON JAVA application

Tags: java, json, cpu-usage

On a quad core CPU machine with 4 gb ram, tomcat 6 installed, Java  1.6.
we have a software who handles as communication gateway.
It handles incoming Json messages using jersey (1.19), deserialize and call a client who send the message to another server using jersey (1.19) rest libraries.
It handles incoming request from the other server, serialize into json and send outside.
With 10 users connected, sending 600 byte of message every 4 seconds. Global cpu consumption reaches 30%.
Is it a normal expected behaviour? how we can handle more users?

code:

```
private String executeToGameEngine(String text, String urlResource){
ClientResponse response = null;
try {           
  ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
  Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
  WebResource webResource = client.resource(urlResource);

  response =
      webResource
          .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
          .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
          .post(ClientResponse.class, text);

  if (response == null) {
    // error...
  }
  else if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                            // error...
  }
  return response.getEntity(String.class);
```

}

We installed visualVM to analyze the problem,
any suggestion?enter image description here

Comment: Do you know how to use VisualVM? Because it can tell you a lot better what's wrong than we can.

Comment: http://imgur.com/QP3wuJW http://imgur.com/iQdCpkC http://imgur.com/iKHtTWI http://imgur.com/Xi1o5fn, these are the images collected from visualVM

Comment: @Kayaman do you have any ideas? any suggestion?

Comment: Well, I see a hotspot method in the images.

Comment: @Kayaman what do you mean? do you think it is the problem?

Comment: Well, it's doing network I/O, so it's no wonder it's a hotspot. Why don't you do some performance testing to see how the amount of users affects the throughput.

Comment: I will try to double the users and post the results like I did, thank you.

Comment: CPU consumption growth linearlly from 30 to 57% passing from 10 to 20 users.

Comment: http://imgur.com/6GGGRV7 http://imgur.com/mZUt6ZP http://imgur.com/TzX1q6l http://imgur.com/c7fsnOA

Comment: I'm not here to analyze your screenshots. There's plenty of information available about how to use VisualVM. I suggest you start reading.